# XPATH String for text not in tags

Tags: python, xpath

I'm looking for a **single** XPATH statement that can select the text in the body but exclude anything in tags, including script tags.

`//body//text()` appears to select both cases.

Here are the two cases:

Case 1:
`<body>
Select this text
</body>`

Case 2:
`<body>
select this text`
`<script>`
`don't select this text`
`</script>
</body>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends of the tools you are using. `xmllint --html --xpath '//body/text()' file` give the expected output

Comment: I am using libxml2 with htmlParseDoc and the //body/text() xpath does not return the needed results (as per the above).

Comment: That xpath is _exactly_ what is needed to handle those cases as you posted... just the text that are direct descendants of `body` tags. If there are more cases, you need to show us.

Comment: @JeffMercado No, that's not true - if by "direct descendants" you mean "immediate children". `//body//text()` is not necessarily the same as `//body/text()`. And, AnonPyDev: What _does_ `//body/text()` return?

Comment: @MathiasMüller: Po-tay-to po-tah-to.  Yeah yeah, that's what I meant. :)

Comment: @JeffMercado Looking again, I see that you were responding to AnonPyDev's comment. I thought you were commenting on the question. That was the confusion, not your wording - apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
//text()[parent::body]
```

when applied to a document like

```
<html>
  <body>YES YES
    <script>NO NO</script>
    YES YES
  </body>
</html>
```

it returns (individual results separated by `-----`)

```
YES YES

-----------------------

YES YES
```